# Create facebook session when Uid and authtoken is received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I have to work on mobile api ,the purpose is to use facebook connect to login and send required data to access the api.
For testing now user provides us with hard coded values of auth token and Uid,so how can i create a session for the user.I'm using facebooker gem ,rails 2.3.4 and ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to need the access_token with offline_access permission, because these access_token hasn't expires time. In PHP, there is a function named setAccessToken(), in this you can set your access token(which has offline_access permission). Below is the code for PHP( Sorry, I don't know about the RoR)

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
   'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$facebook->setAccessToken("...");
```

Comment: thanx for reply but unable to trace the solution